# Python Regex over list of strings

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to extract a url from a list of strings. Sample list:

```
import re
p = ['<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-2087" src="http://www.sample.com/test.jpg" alt="0wCR41v" width="540" height="720" srcset="http://www.sample.com/test-225x300.jpg 225w, http://www.sample.com/test.jpg 540w" sizes="(max-width: 540px) 100vw, 540px" />', '<img class="alignnone size-large wp-image-2133" src="http://www.sample.com/test2.jpg" alt="NtAboHF" width="583" height="1024" srcset="http://www.happyfridaygents.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/NtAboHF-768x1349.jpg 768w, http://www.sample.com/test2.jpg 583w, http://www.happyfridaygents.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/NtAboHF.jpg 828w" sizes="(max-width: 583px) 100vw, 583px" />']
```

I'd like to extract the `http://www.sample.com/test.jpg` part that comes right after the src=" part.

I can use findall if p is just one string like so:

```
t = re.findall('src="(.+)" alt', p)
print t
```

But how can I iterate over the list and return a list of all the urls in P?

Comment: See http://www.cademuir.eu/blog/2011/10/20/python-searching-for-a-string-within-a-list-list-comprehension/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution using `BeautifulSoup`:

```
>>> p = ['<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-2087" src="http://www.sample.com/test.jpg" alt="0wCR41v" width="540" height="720" srcset="http://www.sample.com/test-225x300.jpg 225w, http://www.sample.com/test.jpg 540w" sizes="(max-width: 540px) 100vw, 540px" />', '<img class="alignnone size-large wp-image-2133" src="http://www.sample.com/test2.jpg" alt="NtAboHF" width="583" height="1024" srcset="http://www.happyfridaygents.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/NtAboHF-768x1349.jpg 768w, http://www.sample.com/test2.jpg 583w, http://www.happyfridaygents.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/NtAboHF.jpg 828w" sizes="(max-width: 583px) 100vw, 583px" />']

>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(p), 'html.parser')
>>> src_links = [img['src'] for img in soup.find_all('img')]

>>> src_links
[u'http://www.sample.com/test.jpg', u'http://www.sample.com/test2.jpg']
```

If you do want to use regex:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r'src="(.+)" alt')
>>> [regex.search(img).group(1) for img in p]
['http://www.sample.com/test.jpg', 'http://www.sample.com/test2.jpg']
```

Comment: Thank you. I used the regex version.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you'd like?

```
import re
p = ['<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-2087" src="http://www.sample.com/test.jpg" alt="0wCR41v" width="540" height="720" srcset="http://www.sample.com/test-225x300.jpg 225w, http://www.sample.com/test.jpg 540w" sizes="(max-width: 540px) 100vw, 540px" />', '<img class="alignnone size-large wp-image-2133" src="http://www.sample.com/test2.jpg" alt="NtAboHF" width="583" height="1024" srcset="http://www.happyfridaygents.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/NtAboHF-768x1349.jpg 768w, http://www.sample.com/test2.jpg 583w, http://www.happyfridaygents.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/NtAboHF.jpg 828w" sizes="(max-width: 583px) 100vw, 583px" />']
outList = [re.findall('src="(.+)" alt', pp)[0] for pp in p]
```

Comment: I was only 4 minutes late :)

Comment: Not sure if this is intended but this returns one list but each element (url) is a list itself. Is that right?

Comment: True, I have edited the answer so that each element is just a string, not a list.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension:

```
l = [re.findall('src="(.+)" alt', each_url) for each_url in p]
```

This will give you a list of lists which you can chain together:

```
import itertools
urls = list(itertools.chain(*l))
```

The regex answer given elsewhere is more elegant, though.

Comment: Same applies here that I wrote to Peter. "Not sure if this is intended but this returns one list but each element (url) is a list itself. Is that right?"

Comment: @Bernardo I modified the code to return the list of urls, but I suggest going with the regex way.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check it out when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

What about doing it in a loop:

```
>>> pe = re.compile('src="(.+)" alt')
>>> for img in p:
...     print pe.findall(img)
... 
['http://www.sample.com/test.jpg']
['http://www.sample.com/test2.jpg']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in p:
    t = re.findall('src="(.+)" alt', i)
    print t
```

Update:

```
k=[re.findall('src="(.+)" alt',i) for i in p]
[item for sublist in k for item in sublist]
```

['http://www.sample.com/test.jpg', 'http://www.sample.com/test2.jpg']

Comment: Thanks but this prints two lists. I'm looking for one list of the urls. I guess I could join them.